# Display field's label only when any value added to it

Tags: theming, nodes, 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

For example Taxonomy Terms field **Label** is always displayed even if no tags added to it. How can I show Taxonomy Terms field's Label and its values (tag's links), only when there have been a value added to it?

I try to achieve that by adding conditionals based fields, something like below code to node template:

```
{% if content.field_tag is not empty %}
{{ content.field_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if content.field_tag %}
{{ content.field_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

According to the article:[Comparison of PHP Template and Twig theming paradigms](https://www.drupal.org/node/1918824#conditionals) but whatever I try I can't get any result.

Comment: Are you sure it behaves as the way u explained ?? because i installed fresh drupal and created a content article with no tag the label Tag dint show up

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my mean when you add Taxonomy Terms field to the content, in this case Taxonomy Terms field **`Label`** always be displayed.

Comment: You may have to use form_alter .

Comment: Just for confirmation before posting an answer you are talking abt node-edit page ie node/nid/edit page correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my means not that page.

Comment: Like @ShreyaShetty said, empty fields are not displayed and their title is not shown. Try ot a new installation. It is more likely that you have some kind of template or code somewhere that causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost you did , instead of `content.FIELD_MACHINENAME` use `node.FIELD_MACHINENAME.value`
I mean try something like

```
{% if node.field_tag.value %}
{{ content.field_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

for make sure that this solution work correctly(for debug) try `{{ kint(node.field_tag }}`.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani you're welcome, we are here to help each other.